# Pasting header-text only from OutlineView

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to copy and paste the headings from the outline view into a new
document.

I only want the headings, not all the body text in between. The problem is,
when I select all the headings in outline view, and then paste them into a
new document, it pastes the entire document.

I am aware of workarounds based on selecting all text formatted with Heading styles, or temporarily creating a TOC. But is there a way to paste the headings only, that just uses the Outline View in Word 2016?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "copy visible text" feature in Word. You could make all the body text hidden (select all instances of body text, go into the font settings on the Home tab and select "hidden" checkbox). Just switch it back once you've copied the headings.